slow to open when a excel file with many power query's queries
For some reasons, I have to create a Excel file with 300+ Power Query queries. I found that when open it in Excel 2016 or open Power Query Editor in Excel 2019(or later), a "Loading .NET Framework" at the right-bottom of the Excel window will show up and keep a quite a long time, during which I can't do anything but wait for long.
There is a "bad" solution(text), which clears all then queries in Power Query. So maybe it is associated with .NET Framework and XML, but I cannot go further it due to my lack of knowledge of them.
I wish a better solution that not only does it keep all then queries but also accelerates even eliminates that long-time waiting.

I'll bite. Why do you need 300 power queries in a single file? Can't you batch process whatever you are doing with 1-2 power queries?

Using 300+ queries is ridiculous, and how do you expect all of those to run when the workbook is opened without taking a lot of time? Imagine that you walk up to the front door of your house, which has been locked all day, and having to open 300+ locks on that door, digging through your several dozen key rings to find the right key for each one. It would take quite a while to get in, wouldn't it? What do you think happens when you open your workbook? That all of those magically just run without any impact?

And the better solution you're looking for is to redo whatever it is you're doing where you think you need that many queries in a single workbook. The issue has nothing to do with .NET and/or XML. It has to do with having too many queries in your workbook - when you open it, they start being executed, and they're executed one after another. How long do you think it should take to sequentially run more than 300 queries, even if each one did little or nothing?

I have closed the "background load"(maybe it should be called this way, in Chinese it's called 允许在后台下载数据) in "query options", the queries won't be calculated, so it shall not use a lot of time when opening a Excel workbook. I noticed that mashup.container, which is the program doing Power Query calculations, does not use CPU at all(actually it doesn't show up in task manager at all! ) when opening my 300+ query's workbook. So I guess Excel must be trapped in something redundant, which I do not know how to remove and optimise.
